# How can I set the color of a pixel on a canvas using WebGL?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, webgl

I am very new to WebGL, but not Javascript or Canvas.  Essentially, I need a very fast way to be able to change the color of a pixel on a canvas at any coordinate.  I feel like this could be done using WebGL fragment shaders.  Is this possible, and is there a better way?  How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Just a single pixel? Or a lot of pixels? For a single pixel the call overhead may be worse than just using Canvas2D.

Comment: A lot of pixels.  It's doable with imageData, but too slow for 400x400 pixels.

Comment: Where do you get the pixel data from? If you can calculate the values in the shader all in one batch, WebGL will be faster. If you get the data out of an array, WebGL may not be much faster than imageData.

Comment: They would be from an array, probably.  Thanks for the help, though!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This isn't an exhaustive guide to rendering because it doesn't include the bits about shader management; instead it focuses on how drawing of WebGL primitives is actually performed, and how to use orthographic projection to precisely position vertices on the screen.

For more information, I highly recommend these sources:

- [Learning WebGL - tutorials](http://learningwebgl.com)
- [The WebGL specification](http://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/)
- [The Typed Arrays specification](http://www.khronos.org/registry/typedarray/specs/latest/)

WebGL does all of its drawing with Vertex Buffer Objects (VBOs), so you need to compile all your data into 3D vertices and send them down to the video card in as few VBOs as possible (to maximize performance).

A VBO can be created in WebGL like so:

```
var vbo = gl.createBuffer();
```

Then you need to send the data down to the buffer, usually in the form of a `Float32Array`. If you already have your data in the form of a regular JavaScript array, then you can use `new Float32Array(jsArray)` to initialize the `Float32Array` from the `jsArray`'s contents. Try to do this rarely though. Typed arrays are very fast, but initialize very slowly. It's best to create them once and reuse them whenever possible.

Once you have a `Float32Array`, you can pass the data down to the buffer like so:

```
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, float32Data, gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

You'll need to perform a `bufferData` or `bufferSubData` call every time the data changes.

By this time the data is on the graphics card, so you only need to actually *draw* it:

```
// bind the VBO to be drawn if you haven't already
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
// send the vertex data to the shader program
gl.vertexAttribPointer(vertexAttributeLocation, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
// draw the buffer
gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, float32Data.length / 3);
```

Note that although the graphics card can hold quite a few VBOs, you should use as few of them as possible, because the more `drawArrays` calls you have to perform, the slower things are going to get. Indeed, if you render only a single pixel at a time in a given VBO, it's going to be too slow to run.

The reason the length of the `Float32Array` is divided by 3 is because each single data element is a 3D (X, Y, Z) coordinate, so each data element consists of 3 float components. Note that the first argument to `gl.drawArrays` was `gl.POINTS`. This instructs the graphics card to draw a single point (by default, a single pixel in size) for each item in the array. There are other ways to draw, and if you need to *fill* a group of pixels, one of the other draw modes (e.g. `gl.TRIANGLES`) may be more to your liking.

As for lighting up specific pixels, it depends on how the shader is written, but *most likely* you're making use of a modelview matrix and a projection matrix. The modelview matrix represents the orientation of the camera relative to the points being drawn, and the projection matrix represents the camera dimensions (width and height, field of view, nearest and furthest visible ranges, etc). So if you want to light specific pixels, your best bet is to apply an *orthographic* projection matrix with a width and height equal to the width and height of the canvas; and a modelview matrix set to the identity (no transformation). In an orthographic projection, objects don't shrink as they get further away from the camera, so they're very helpful for specifying exact positions relative to the screen. Also, if you give them the proper dimensions, you can position vertices very precisely -- *at specific pixels*, if you wish.

Different matrix libraries work in different ways, but for example, to set up an orthographic matrix in [gl-matrix](http://github.com/toji/gl-matrix), you can do so like this:

```
var ortho = mat4.ortho(left, right, bottom, top, near, far);
```

The exact numbers depend on your preference; if you'd like to place the origin (0, 0) at the bottom-left of the canvas, you'd do so like this:

```
var ortho = mat4.ortho(0, canvas.width, 0, canvas.height, 0.01, 200);
```

Note that the Z value of each point still has to lie between `near` and `far` in order to be rendered, however, and the `near` value cannot be set to `0`.

Let me know if any of this needs clarifying.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to draw single pixels you're probably better off using canvas 2d.

Otherwise you can probably figure it out from this tutorial which draws rectangles in pixel units so set the width and height to 1x1 and you'll get single pixels.

http://games.greggman.com/game/webgl-fundamentals/

Answer (score 2):

You could use GL_POINTS when drawing. Basically you would pass an array of points to the GPU, together with the colors and the positions. You then call drawArrays with the right data.

This might be too tied to other things, but this might help you:

https://github.com/funkaster/ChesterGL/blob/master/chesterGL/primitivesBlock.js#L126

https://github.com/funkaster/ChesterGL/blob/master/chesterGL/primitivesBlock.js#L260

That's how I render several points in the primitive block for chesterGL.